# Passing string variable through function in python 3.7.6

Tags: python, string, function

Help! I am trying to pass string through function call ping( "name") so I can pass string "compute1_led" to "computer2_led".. so on as I am reading from a text file. I try different option with no luck. Any help I would appreciated.

```
def ping(self,IP,name):

    #Do ping with "IP"

    if "Lost = 0" in resp_ascii:
    self.('%s'%name).setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 255, 0);\n" "") # LED green <==problem
    
    else:
    self.('%s'%name).setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n" "")  #LED Red  <==problem
```

Comment: What are you passing as `name` and what do you expect the result of `self.('%s'%name)computer1_led` to be?

Comment: I am reading a file line by line and it will be name=computer1_led and i would like to update a line that "self.computer1_led.set Style... and next go around I would like to change to computer2_led.setStyle.. so on. But I am having difficult time passing name.

Comment: You have a fundamental issue here, your `self.computer1_led` etc should probably be stored in a `dict` instead. You can hack your way around with `eval`, but it's extremely unsafe and error prone

Comment: IIUC: Looks like you need the `getattr` function to convert the string into the class attribute to be called.

Comment: Understood and Thanks!  I need to read up on getattr function and see how can I apply.

Comment: Any help or general direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the contents of the name string looks something like a keyword argument list, is that correct?  Are there more than one key=value pairs in your string?  You will have to parse this string yourself to extract the value.   Then you can use that with getattr()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.` with an expression, use `getattr`:

```py
getattr(self, name).setStyleSheet("...")
```

Comment: I think there was a parsing of the name string required as well, looking at the question.  Something like `name.split("=")[1].strip()` as a crude example.

Comment: OMG.. Thank you so much. I am struggle on how to use getattr. Now I understand. Thanks again for your help!